# For-loop doesn't compile

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Please help how to fix my for loop , i was a newbie using Adobe Flash . 
This is my codes.

```
for (int i=0;i< nodes.lenght;i++)
```

[image]

Comment: There is a typo: `nodes.lenght` should be `node.length`

Comment: Voted down. It's more than just a typo, the user has never used AS3 before and obviously didn't even tried to read any basic tutorial or as3 docs or anything purely basic concerning AS3. SO is not meant to teach basic programming syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in syntax:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < nodes.lenght; i++)
{
}
```

P.S.: please, pay more attention to formatting of your question and to the correct topic.

Comment: i was trying to say is, please check may for loop. .. thats all. :D